# How to add border to a rounded rectangle in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to make a button for a website in Illustrator and so far I have a rounded rectangle with a gradient. I want there to be a thin border around the edges of the rectangle, but I can't figure out how to do this (I'm very new to Illustrator).

How can I add a border to the rounded rectangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all click on your shape to highlight it.

You should see two boxes in the top left hand corner. The first of which is your fill color (inside) the second one your stroke color. You need to select your desired stroke color here.

Lastly, you can change the thickness of your stroke be altering the details in the box just right of the stroke selector and labelled stroke.

Maybe you have already created the stroke but it has been too thin to see or a non contrasting colour.

Comment: Also, stroke is a border by the way (just in case)